# xsl: remove namespaces then transform elements

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have a XML like this: `input.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<somens:Root xmlns:somens="http://url/of/some/namespace">
  <somens:Child>
    <somens:String>some value here</somens:String>
    <somens:Integer>123456</somens:Integer>
    <somens:Date>1990-01-01 00:00:00</somens:Date>
    <somens:Element>
      <somens:name>foo</somens:name>
      <somens:value>foo</somens:value>
    </somens:Element>
    <somens:Element>
      <somens:name>foo</somens:name>
      <somens:value>bar</somens:value>
    </somens:Element>
    <somens:Element>
      <somens:name>bar</somens:name>
      <somens:value>bar</somens:value>
    </somens:Element>
  </somens:Child>
</somens:Root>
```

And then should:

- remove all namespaces
- transform `<Element><name>foo</name><value>foo</value></Element><Element><name>foo</name><value>bar</value></Element>` 
  into `<Element><foo>foo</foo><foo>bar</foo></Element>`

`output.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root>
  <Child>
    <String>some value here</String>
    <Integer>123456</Integer>
    <Date>1990-01-01 00:00:00</Date>
    <Element>
      <foo>foo</foo>
      <foo>bar</foo>
      <bar>bar</bar>
    </Element>
  </Child>
</Root>
```

I can remove namespaces with xslt like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="*">
    <!-- remove element prefix -->
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
      <!-- process attributes -->
      <xsl:for-each select="@*">
        <!-- remove attribute prefix -->
        <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}">
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:for-each>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And then transform `Element`s with this xslt:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="//Element">
      <xsl:element name="{./name}">
      <xsl:value-of select="./value"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And got xml like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root>
  <Child>
    <String>some value here</String>
    <Integer>123456</Integer>
    <Date>1990-01-01 00:00:00</Date>
    <foo>foo</foo>
    <foo>bar</foo>
    <bar>bar</bar>
  </Child>
</Root>
```

But i can't understand how i could:

1. make all transformation with single xslt
2. cut childrens from all `Element`s and apply them into single `Element`

Comment: So what is the final result you expect to get?

Comment: @michael.hor257k example at the top of post
```<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root>
  <Child>
    <String>some value here</String>
    <Integer>123456</Integer>
    <Date>1990-01-01 00:00:00</Date>
    <Element>
      <foo>foo</foo>
      <foo>bar</foo>
      <bar>bar</bar>
    </Element>
  </Child>
</Root>```

Comment: Please don't post code in comments. Add this to your question.

Comment: OK, i put labels of input/output xmls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution found!

Thanks @michael.hor257k

`transform.xsl`

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- move all elements to no-namespace -->
<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[*[local-name()='Element']]">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(local-name()='Element')]"/>
        <Element>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*[local-name()='Element']"/>
        </Element>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[local-name()='Element']">
    <xsl:element name="{*[local-name()='name']}">
        <xsl:value-of select="*[local-name()='value']"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I don't think this is a good method. One must assume that a namespace is used for a reason and ignoring it may produce unexpected results. It is unlikely that the schema of the input XML is unknown to such degree. It is more likely that you need to deal with several possible known schemas. In such case you can use a construct like: `<xsl:template match="somens:Child | another:Name">` to deal with several possible namespaces and/or element names.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the result shown in your question using a single XSLT stylesheet like:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:somens="http://url/of/some/namespace"
exclude-result-prefixes="somens">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- move all elements to no-namespace -->
<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="somens:Child">
    <Child>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(self::somens:Element)]"/>
        <Element>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="somens:Element"/>
        </Element>
    </Child>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="somens:Element">
    <xsl:element name="{somens:name}">
        <xsl:value-of select="somens:value"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: ```<foo>foo</foo>
    <foo>bar</foo>
    <bar>bar</bar>``` elements should be wrapped into `Element` like this: ```<Element><foo>foo</foo>
    <foo>bar</foo>
    <bar>bar</bar></Element>```

Comment: Some times xml can have different namespaces and i'm looking for universal solution based on local-name structure..

Comment: You know the structure, but not the namespace??

Comment: Structures of xml may be different too. But all them have similar elements.
For example, `Root` and `Child` elements can have another names

Comment: If you do not know the namespace, but do know the local name, you can use an expression like `<xsl:template match="*[local-name()='Element']">` instead of `<xsl:template match="somens:Element">` and so on. But this is highly unusual. As a rule, an XSLT stylesheet is custom-written to transform from one known schema to another known schema.

Comment: @michael.hor275k yup this is unusual, but can solve unusual task.

Comment: Can't you make the adaption yourself?

Comment: @michael.hor275k can u explain how i can get parent of `Element` for `<xsl:template match="somens:Child">` without knowing of parent name?!

Comment: If you don't know even the local name of the element (but do know that it is a parent of `*:Element`), you can use `<xsl:template match="*[*[local-name()='Element']]">`.  I think you need to post a new question if this doesn't solve your problem.

Comment: @michael.hor275k thank you so much! It solves my question. I'll post solution.